# Output an Entire OpenLDAP Directory

Tags: openldap

How can I retrieve the entire output of an OpenLDAP directory to which I have administrative privileges?

Specifically, I need `dn`, `objectClass`, and (if exists for the object) `uidNumber` or `gidNumber`.

Comment: I ran `ldapsearch -x -LLL -b dc=mydomain,dc=tld` and received two results: the default admin and the top,dcObject,organization object. Is this everything in the directory? I see no option for recursing, so I am inclined to think so, but have nothing to compare it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind to the server using the root DN while performing the search.  That is, use the `-D` and `-W` options to `ldapsearch`.  Otherwise, it is possible that ACLs can cause certain entries or attributes to be suppressed from the results.  Also, use `-s sub` to search recursively.

Alternatively, you could dump the database contents directly, bypassing `slapd`, by running `slapcat` on the server machine.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `ldapsearch -LLL -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=tld -W -s sub -b dc=tohuw,dc=net` and got the same results, except it also included a hash of the admin user's password. Is it therefore safe to assume this constitutes everything in the DIT?

Comment: I did some further reading and found that it is, indeed, everything in the DIT. Thanks for your help!